# How to fetch Linkedin user educations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linkedin-api

I am using Linkedin API to fetch user content in RoR project. i am getting all basic profile info but not getting education info. Here is controller code:

```
client = get_client
educations = client.profile(:fields => [:educations]).educations.all
```

it gives me an error

```
undefined method `all' for nil:NilClass
```

in my linkedin account i add more than one education details but still getting error.

Comment: https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/fields/education

Comment: i use following code

educations = client.profile(:fields => ["field-of-study", "start-date", "end-date" ,"degree", "activities", "notes"])

but it gives me 

(400): Unknown field {degree} in resource {Person} error  for each field